# edit a file line by line interactively from user input in python

Tags: python, file, edit

I want to know how to edit a file on the fly row by row in python.

For example I have a text file where I usually have:

```
key value
key value
key value
key value
key value
...
```

they are not necessarily the same pair for each line. It's just the way I explained it.

I would like to show line by line key and value (on my terminal) and then I want to do one of this two things:

-just press enter (or whatever hot-key) to go ahead and read (show) next line.

-enter a new value then hit enter. this will actually replace the value (that was being shown) on the file and finally go ahead to show next pair of key values.

Till end of file or possibly till I type 'quit' or some other keyword. doesn't matter.

-Being able to go back to the previous row would be a plus (in case of accidentally going to next row), but it's not too important for now.

I find myself often editing huge files in a very tedious and repetitive way, and text editors are really frustrating with their cursors going everywhere when pressing the arrow-key. Also having to use the backspace to delete is annoying.

I know how to read a file and how to write a file in python. But not in such interactive way. I only know how to write the whole file at once. Plus I wouldn't know if it is safe to open the same file in both reading and writing. Also I know how to manipulate each line, split the text in a list of values etc... all I really need is to understand how to modify the file at that exact current line and handle well this type of interaction.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can't edit files in place unless you're replacing things with other things of the exact same length. Your filesystem simply doesn't make it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers focus on loading the contents of the file in memory, modifying and then on close saving all on disk, so I thought I'd give it a try:

```
import os

sep = " "

with open("inline-t.txt", "rb+") as fd:
    seekpos = fd.tell()
    line = fd.readline()
    while line:
        print line
        next = raw_input(">>> ")
        if next == ":q":
            break
        if next:
            values = line.split(sep)
            newval = values[0] + sep + next + '\n'
            if len(newval) == len(line):
                fd.seek(seekpos)
                fd.write(newval)
                fd.flush()
                os.fsync(fd)
            else:
                remaining = fd.read()
                fd.seek(seekpos)
                fd.write(newval + remaining)
                fd.flush()
                os.fsync(fd)
                fd.seek(seekpos)
                line = fd.readline()
        seekpos = fd.tell()
        line = fd.readline()
```

The script simply opens the file, reads line by line, and rewrites it if the user inputs a new value. If the length of the data matches previous data, seek and write are enough. If the new data is of different size, we need to clean-up after us. So the remainder of the file is read, appended to the new data, and everything is rewritten to disk. fd.flush and os.fsync(fd) guarantee that changes are indeed available in the file as soon as it is written out. Not the best solution, performance-wise, but I believe this is closer to what he asked.

Also, consider there might be a few quirks in this code, and I'm sure there's room for optimizing -- perhaps one global read at the beggining to avoid multiple whole file reads if changes that need adjusting are made often, or something like that.

Comment: Ok awesome your solution actually saves the file on the go, althought it has some problems with writing the values at the correct position.But this is a great starting point. I think i can fix it.

Comment: Glad I could help, I just threw the script together from some code I had from an old project that needed to update files on the go. I had the feeling that some more cleanup was needed after the writes. BTW, keep in mind that flush and fsync *need* to stick together, as some OS's have another buffering stage that is cleared with fsync.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about this is to load all the lines of the text file in a list, and then iterate through that list, changing the values of the list as you go along. Then at the very end (when you get to the last line or whenever you want), you will write that whole list out to the file with the same name, so that way it will overwrite the old file.

Comment: Okay, I might go this way but I need to be on the safe side: what if while I am editing the file (or list in this case) something goes wrong, and maybe throws an exception cause a line in the file as a weird character or whatever... I am going to lose all the work I had done so far? That is also why I wanted to edit the file as I go...

Comment: You could move the file to a backup like `Filename-backup.extension`, so that way in case something does go wrong you have a backup